# How do I connect my ps4 controller to my pc using bluetooth

Tags: controllers, ps4, windows-7

Can anyone tell me how to connect my PS4 controller to my PC using Bluetooth?

I am running Windows 7 with a generic Bluetooth dongle if that' important

I have watched a lot of videos on YouTube but it doesn't work for me. I can connect it and it pairs and in devices and printers it shows up as a wireless game controller, but Windows doesn't recognize it as a game controller which stops it from showing up in DS4Windows or Input Mapper (programs that make Windows think its an Xbox 360 controller).

It works fine when its connected through USB so I know the controller works.

If anyone has had this problem and knows how to fix it please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Newer operating systems can pair normally, older ones require an additional driver (or 2 if you decide to use software).

Either way you need a setup Bluetooth adapter (duh).

**If you're on windows 10/8** (with fully customizable game), just pair controller as a normal Bluetooth device and you should be ready to play. Pairing process goes something like this:

- Make sure your PS4 (or anything else controller is connected to) is off or unpaired. (If you've got it paired to PS4, safest bet is to power it off and unplug it if  you don't want to unpair.
- Open Bluetooth pairing interface on your PC.
- Hold PS button (round button at the center) until controller turns on and light flashes
- Controller should show up as pairable on PC, so pair it.

**If you're on win 7 on older OS** (would also suggest for Win 8/10 too):

- Get [DS4Windows](http://ds4windows.com/) (easy driver install and helps with remapping).
- Launch it and install DS4 driver (just a button click)
- Install Xbox360 accessory driver (another button click).
- Pair via Bluetooth as usual.
- Now you're ready to play, but you can also re-open DS4 Windows and configure your PS4 controller to act as Xbox or just remap keys.

[This article](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/gaming/how-to-use-the-ps4-dualshock-4-controller-on-a-pc-1309014) might help you out, and I'm sure there are YouTube videos covering this topic.